# iOS Stripe webview 3d secure conformation issue: webview doesn't close automatically

Tags: flutter, webview, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I'm testing a payment through [stripe_payment](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment/example) lib by card with a 3d secure enabled on iOS 14.0.
Here's what I'm doing:

1. Calling back-end endpoint to init setup intent. It responds with a secret

   var secret = await apiService.initPaymentMethod();
2. Than I'm creating payment method using

   method = await stripeService.createPaymentMethod(CreditCard(number: cardNumber, expYear: int.tryParse(expYear), expMonth: int.tryParse(expMonth), cvc: svv));

cardNumber is entered in UI manually, it's one of test Stripe card numbers that require 3d secure authentication. I took it from here https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards

3. After I got the paymentMethodId I call payment completion like this:

   result = await StripePayment.confirmSetupIntent(
   PaymentIntent(
   clientSecret: secret,
   paymentMethodId: paymentMethodId,
   returnURL: 'kavall://stripe-redirect',
   ),
   );
4. After that I see a Safari webview which allows me to complete the 3d secure check.
   Then it redirects to a page with a button saying "Return to merchant". The button doesn't work. And the webview must be closed manually by pressing Close button in the top left corner.
   Meanwhile I see that the payment is really completed in my app's console. The deep link is really triggered. If I do not pass returnURL, nothing happens at this step. So it works. The only problem is that Safari isn't closing. Is there a way to make it close automatically?

Comment: Do you have your custom URL scheme registered and do you have your AppDelegate setup to notify the Stripe SDK when it gets hit? If not(or it that unofficial Flutter library doesn't support a way to call into {{StripeAPI.handleURLCallback}} in the native stripe-ios SDK then this won't work.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#when-to-use-3d-secure , under the iOS tab, shows how to use this. 


https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/StripeAPI.html#/c:@M@Stripe@objc(cs)StripeAPI(cm)handleStripeURLCallbackWithURL:

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people have this issue but it seems to be caused by

- either bad scheme url
- or not handling the URL
  .. my issue was the latter

*other examples:* [see here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/1372)

when creating the payment intent (that's when you call `initPaymentSheet(..)`), make sure you pass the `returnURL` parameter (I think most likely you are doing that already else you would have been seeing a message saying something like Authentication is complete, close your window) -- anyhow, for the next person reading this, make sure your URL matches that scheme in app config (in my example below my returnURL would be something like `my-appy://stripe-payment`)

So then, after doing that bit above, follow these steps and use the handle url methods that are somewhat documented here:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet

**Modified from above link with a bit more in depth pointers**

```js
/** app.config.js or app.config.ts has the scheme **/


const effectiveScheme = 'my-appy';

  export default {
    name: '.......',
    slug: '....',
    version: '1.0.0',
    scheme: effectiveScheme,
    orientation: 'portrait',
    icon: './assets/icon.png',
    userInterfaceStyle: 'light',
    extra: {
      ...
    },
    splash: {
      image: './assets/splash.png',
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    updates: {
      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0,
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: ['**/*'],
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
      googleServicesFile: './GoogleService-Info.plist',
      bundleIdentifier: 'com.bar.foo.expo.ios',
      infoPlist: {
        NSCameraUsageDescription:
          'blah blah',
        NSAllowsArbitraryLoads: true,
        NSAllowsLocalNetworking: true,
        // LSApplicationQueriesSchemes: [effectiveScheme],
      },
      associatedDomains: [`applinks:${effectiveScheme}`],
    },
    android: {
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: './assets/splash.png',
        monochromeImage: './assets/splash.png',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      },
      versionCode: 19,
      googleServicesFile: './google-services.json',
      package: 'com.bar.foo.expo.android',
    },
    web: {
      favicon: './assets/favicon.png',
    },
    plugins: [
      [
        '@stripe/stripe-react-native',
        {
          merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.com.bar.foo.expo.ios',
          enableGooglePay: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
  }
```

```js
/** My App.tsx has linking setup **/
...
...
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
...
const prefix = Linking.createURL('');

export const App = () => {

   const linking: LinkingOptions<ReactNavigation.RootParamList> = {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Home: 'stripe-payment?*',
      },
    },
  };
   const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef<RootNavigationProp>();

   return <>
          <NavigationContainer linking={linking} ref={navigationRef}>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Empty">
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Splash"
              options={{headerLeft: undefined, headerShown: false}}
              component={AppSplashScreen}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Login"
              options={{headerLeft: undefined, headerShown: false}}
              component={LoginScreen}
            />

           ......

          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>

    </>
}
```

```js
/** HERE IS MY PAYMENT COMPONENT OR RATHER SOMETHING LIKE THIS */
/** What made it work for me is this handle URL methods - before it the return to merchant didn't close */

import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
import { useStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';

export default MyPaymentComponent = () => {
  const { handleURLCallback, /* and other things that you must already have */ } = useStripe();

  const handleDeepLink = useCallback(
    async (url: string | null) => {
      if (url) {
        const stripeHandled = await handleURLCallback(url);
        if (stripeHandled) {
          // This was a Stripe URL - you can return or add extra handling here as you see fit
        } else {
          // This was NOT a Stripe URL – handle as you normally would
        }
      }
    },
    [handleURLCallback]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUrlAsync = async () => {
      const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      handleDeepLink(initialUrl);
    };

    getUrlAsync();

    const deepLinkListener = Linking.addEventListener(
      'url',
      (event: { url: string }) => {
        handleDeepLink(event.url);
      }
    );

    return () => deepLinkListener.remove();
  }, [handleDeepLink]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is my supposed payment screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```